# creating pg_cron extension within docker-entrypoint-initdb.d fails

Tags: postgresql, docker, psql, timescaledb

If I create the [pg_cron](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron) extension in a `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql` file, the docker image fails to run and `docker logs <id>` just says "No such container." Here's the relevant .sql snippet:

```
CREATE DATABASE my_database;
\c my_database;
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis CASCADE;
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS timescaledb CASCADE;
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_cron CASCADE;
```

However, if I create the pg_cron extension after the docker run command completes (i.e. remove the last line above and run it separately with `psql --file` after `docker run` completes), the extension gets created successfully (postgis and timescaledb extensions seem to be fine regardless).

Is there a reason I can't create the pg_cron extension from `docker-entrypoint-init.d`? Is there a correct place?

My docker run command is as follows:

```
 docker run -d \
        --name my_container --rm \
        -p 5432:5432 \
        -clog_line_prefix="%m [%p]: [%l-1] %u@%d" \
        -clog_error_verbosity=VERBOSE \
        -cshared_preload_libraries='timescaledb,pg_cron' \
        -ccron.database_name='my_database'
```

Answer (score 6):

`pg_cron` can be loaded only as shared library. You must specify it in `postgres.conf` file. Since all scripts in `docker-entrypoint-init.d` are executed after postgres server is started (with `pg_ctl start`), all changes to `shared_preload_libraries` in `postgres.conf` can become available after restart (with `pg_ctl restart`).

Real world example:

*002-setup.sh*:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Remove last line "shared_preload_libraries='citus'"
sed -i '$ d' ${PGDATA}/postgresql.conf

cat <<EOT >> ${PGDATA}/postgresql.conf
shared_preload_libraries='pg_cron,citus'
cron.database_name='${POSTGRES_DB:-postgres}'
EOT

# Required to load pg_cron
pg_ctl restart
```

*003-main.sql*:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_cron;
```

**Notice**:

1. script execution order matters and is ordered by file names
2. `pg_cron` becomes available in **db** specified with `cron.database_name`

Comment: This is not enough, you actually need to install the extension prior to reference it in PostgreSQL configuration

Answer (score 3):

The proposed solution didn't work with a newly created container for me. So, I did it like this:

**Docker file**

```
FROM postgres:13.2

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install git build-essential postgresql-server-dev-13

RUN git clone https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron.git
RUN cd pg_cron && make && make install

RUN cd / && \
        rm -rf /pg_cron && \
        apt-get remove -y git build-essential postgresql-server-dev-13 && \
        apt-get autoremove --purge -y && \
        apt-get clean && \
        apt-get purge

COPY init-db /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

**init-db/002-pg-cron.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# use same db as the one from env
dbname="$POSTGRES_DB"

# create custom config
customconf=/var/lib/postgresql/data/custom-conf.conf
echo "" > $customconf
echo "shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_cron'" >> $customconf
echo "cron.database_name = '$dbname'" >> $customconf
chown postgres $customconf
chgrp postgres $customconf

# include custom config from main config
conf=/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
found=$(grep "include = '$customconf'" $conf)
if [ -z "$found" ]; then
  echo "include = '$customconf'" >> $conf
fi
```

Also, you can place other init files into init-db directory.

**003-main.sql**

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_cron;
```

**Docker compose file**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: your-container
    build: .
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "your_db"
      POSTGRES_USER: "your_user"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "your_user"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
volumes:
  pgdata:
    driver: local
```

Comment: Hi Petro,

How 002-pg-cron.sh file will be executed in the above steps? I was expecting some ENTRYPOINT ["init-db/002-pg-cron.sh"] at the end of the DockerFile. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi @Rizwan. Please pay attention to the last row of the Dockerfile. The [official postgres docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/) will run `.sql` and `.sh` scripts found in the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` folder.

Comment: Thank you Petro for your message and clarification. This now makes complete sense to me.

Comment: In your solution is missing `pg_ctl restart` at the end of the `002-pg-cron.sh file` and with that everything is running smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install & setup `pg_cron` extension.

I recommend you to use (or at least fork) this repository : [ramazanpolat/postgres_cron: Dockerfile for building postgresql:11 with pg_cron extension](https://github.com/ramazanpolat/postgres_cron)