# Installing and using pg_cron extension on Postgres running inside of Docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I tried installing [`pg_cron`](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron) on Postgres running inside a Docker container but getting this error `could not access file "pg_cron": No such file or directory`. Any ideas on how to resolve?

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/51797554, I tried the following:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  pg:
    container_name: pg-container
    image: postgres:11.5
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "pgdb"
      POSTGRES_USER: "pguser"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "pgpass"
    volumes:
      - ./:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
      - pgstorage
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

volumes:
  pgstorage:
```

**002-setup.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
# Remove last line "shared_preload_libraries='citus'"
sed -i '$ d' ${PGDATA}/postgresql.conf
cat <<EOT >> ${PGDATA}/postgresql.conf
shared_preload_libraries='pg_cron'
cron.database_name='${POSTGRES_DB:-postgres}'
EOT
# Required to load pg_cron
pg_ctl restart
```

**003-main.sql**

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_cron;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can see you are not [installing](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron#installing-pg_cron) pg_cron anywhere. Since it is not packaged with the default Postgres Docker image you will have to care of that.

For example by extending the Image and using a `build` entry in your `docker-compose.yml`.

```
# Dockerfile relative to docker-compose.yml

FROM postgres:11.5

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install git build-essential postgresql-server-dev-11

RUN git clone https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron.git
RUN cd pg_cron && make && make install
```

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  pg:
    container_name: pg-container
    build: .
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "pgdb"
      POSTGRES_USER: "pguser"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "pgpass"
    volumes:
      - ./:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

In newer versions of Postgres - you can install the `pg_cron` extension with `apt-get`.

```
FROM postgres:16-bookworm
RUN apt-get update &&  \ 
  apt-get -y install postgresql-16-cron && \ 
  apt-get clean \ 
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

This will take care of the "installation" part. It is also necessary to configure `pg_cron` and finally create the extension.

```
# add to postgresql.conf

# required to load pg_cron background worker on start-up
shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_cron'

# optionally, specify the database in which the pg_cron background worker should run (defaults to postgres)
cron.database_name = 'postgres'
```

Alternatively, with Docker Compose these configuration values can also be passed as a `command` entry:

```yaml
services:
  db:
    build: .
    command:
      [
        "postgres",
        "-c",
        "log_statement=all",
        "-c",
        "log_destination=stderr",
        "-c",
        "shared_preload_libraries=pg_cron",
        "-c",
        "cron.database_name=${POSTGRES_DB-postgres}",
      ]
```

Finally, you will have to create the extension (in a migration script, init script or else).

```sql
-- run as superuser:
CREATE EXTENSION pg_cron;

-- optionally, grant usage to regular users:
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA cron TO marco;
```

Loading the extension and activating it (create extension...) can be done in multiple ways in Docker: https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/

> This worked for me - it probably needs some more optimization.

Comment: This solution isn't working for me, unfortunately. Any hints?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77979910/docker-postgresql-pg-cron-unrecognized-configuration-parameter-cron-databa

Comment: Not working for me as well, something has changed recently because it was working before using this method

Answer (score 3):

The proposed solution didn't work with a newly created container for me. So, I did it like this:

**Docker file**

```
FROM postgres:11.5

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install git build-essential postgresql-server-dev-11

RUN git clone https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron.git
RUN cd pg_cron && make && make install

RUN cd / && \
        rm -rf /pg_cron && \
        apt-get remove -y git build-essential postgresql-server-dev-11 && \
        apt-get autoremove --purge -y && \
        apt-get clean && \
        apt-get purge

COPY init-db /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

**init-db/pg-cron.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# use same db as the one from env
dbname="$POSTGRES_DB"

# create custom config
customconf=/var/lib/postgresql/data/custom-conf.conf
echo "" > $customconf
echo "shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_cron'" >> $customconf
echo "cron.database_name = '$dbname'" >> $customconf
chown postgres $customconf
chgrp postgres $customconf

# include custom config from main config
conf=/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
found=$(grep "include = '$customconf'" $conf)
if [ -z "$found" ]; then
  echo "include = '$customconf'" >> $conf
fi
```

Also, you can place other init files into init-db directory.

**Docker compose file**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: your-container
    build: .
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: "your_db"
      POSTGRES_USER: "your_user"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "your_user"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
volumes:
  pgdata:
    driver: local
```

Answer (score 3):

For postgres 15.4 you can just do:

```
FROM postgres:15.4
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl


RUN apt-get -y install postgresql-15-cron
RUN echo "shared_preload_libraries='pg_cron'" >> /usr/share/postgresql/postgresql.conf.sample
RUN echo "cron.database_name='your_db_name'" >> /usr/share/postgresql/postgresql.conf.sample
```

And after that you can create

Answer (score 1):

Nothing above worked for me.
Used following procedure in the end:

```
git clone https://github.com/ramazanpolat/postgres_cron.git
cd postgres_cron
```

In this directory edit Dockerfile to this:

```
    FROM postgres:15.1
LABEL MAINTAINER Michael Spitzer <professa@gmx.net>

ENV PG_CRON_VERSION "1.4.2"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    postgresql-server-dev-15 postgresql-contrib-15 \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    wget jq cmake build-essential ca-certificates && \
    mkdir /build && \
    cd /build && \
    wget https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron/archive/v$PG_CRON_VERSION.tar.gz && \
    tar xzvf v$PG_CRON_VERSION.tar.gz && \
    cd pg_cron-$PG_CRON_VERSION && \
    make && \
    make install && \
    cd / && \
    rm -rf /build && \
    apt-get remove -y wget jq cmake build-essential ca-certificates && \
    apt-get autoremove --purge -y && \
    apt-get clean && \
    apt-get purge && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN echo "shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_cron'" >> /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
RUN echo "cron.database_name = '${PG_CRON_DB:-pg_cron}'" >> /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf

COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]

EXPOSE 5432
CMD ["postgres"]
```

After that

```
docker build -t postgres_cron:15 .
```

Run it:

```
docker run --name postgresql -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=YourPassword -p 5432:5432 -v /data:/var/lib/postgresql/data -d postgres_cron:15
```

Replace `YourPassword` with your password.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are looking for a ready image, please try the following:

```bash
docker pull ramazanpolat/postgres_cron:11
```